# Apache 2.4 - 403 HTTP status code

Tags: php, virtualhost, apache-2.4, hosts, http-status-code-403

I'm getting a 403 error message with Apache, in Debian Testing.

Apache version:

```
# aptitude show apache2 | grep -i version
Version: 2.4.9-1

# ls -la /home/

total 28
drwxr-xr-x  4 root    root     4096 Apr  3 13:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root    root     4096 Apr  4 07:28 ..
drwx------  2 root    root    16384 Apr  3 13:13 lost+found
drwx--x--x 36 username username  4096 Apr  7 13:30 username

# ls -la /home/username/Development/PHP/foo.dev.com/

total 16
drwx--x--x 4 username username 4096 Apr  3 14:35 .
drwx--x--x 6 username username 4096 Apr  3 14:36 ..
drwx--x--x 2 username username 4096 Apr  3 14:35 logs
drwx--x--x 8 username username 4096 Apr  3 14:35 public_html

# cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.com.conf
UseCanonicalName Off

<VirtualHost *>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/home/username/Development/PHP/%0/public_html/"
    <Directory "/home/username/Development/PHP/%0/public_html/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Mon Apr 07 14:08:15.069251 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 8649] [client 127.0.0.1:48578] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/username/Development/PHP/foo.dev.com/public_html/
```

Firefox, "No proxy for" configuration:
    `localhost, 127.0.0.1, *.dev.com`

```
# cat /etc/hosts:
hosts        hosts.allow  hosts.deny
root@username:/home# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   username.mymachine.local    username

# Custom
127.0.0.1   teste.dev.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

## UPDATE 1:

SELinux does not seems to be installed:

```
$ aptitude search ~i | grep selinux
i   libselinux1                     - SELinux runtime shared libraries
```

## UPDATE 2:

```
$ ls -la /home/
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  4 root    root     4096 Apr  3 13:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root    root     4096 Apr  4 07:28 ..
drwx------  2 root    root    16384 Apr  3 13:13 lost+found
drwx--xr-x 38 username username  4096 Apr  9 08:26 username
```

Comment: What about the other directories between `/home/username` and `/home/username/Development/PHP/foo.dev.com/public_html` - do they also allow access?

Comment: I've executed chmod recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> client denied by server configuration:
>   /home/username/Development/PHP/foo.dev.com/public_html/

This make me think about a similar issue i had :

Ensure that `www-data` user has the `x` bit permission set for **each folders** on the path to `/home/username/Development/PHP/foo.dev.com/public_html`

Either by making `www-data` the owner of the folders : `chown www-data`

Or grant the `x` bit to `others` : `chmod o+x`

**EDIT :**

Finally i have been able to reproduce. It seems that `%0` is not supported in `<Directory>` directive. I have corrected this adding a `*` instead :

```
UseCanonicalName Off
<VirtualHost *>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/home/username/Development/PHP/%0/public_html/"
    <Directory "/home/username/Development/PHP/*/public_html/">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: "chmod -R o+x username/" doesn't change anything. The error remains the same. Thank you.

Comment: And what are rhe permissions for `/home` ?

Comment: Please check the update 2 above. Thanks.

Comment: It shows permissions for `username` directory, not for `home` directory. I would like to see permissions for `/home` directoty, not `username` directory : `ls -ld /home`

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Apr  3 13:19 /home

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `<Directory>`-directive accepts `%0` as part of the path name, in the documentation only regexps are mentioned: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory

Whereas ´%0´ is part of the vhost_alias-module:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

You might try changing

`<Directory "/home/username/Development/PHP/%0/public_html/">`

to:

`<Directory "/home/username/Development/PHP/">`

and see if this is the case. You can also probably try with regexp `/home/username/Development/PHP/*/public_html/`

Comment: It accepted in a CentOS 6.5 box with httpd 2.2. Maybe it has changed with 2.4 ...

Comment: Oh, did you check if SELinux context is `httpd_sys_content_t`with `ls -Z`, if you have it on?

Answer (score 0):

> client denied by server configuration: /home/username/Development/PHP/foo.dev.com/public_html/

It should be obvious that....

```
ls -la /home/username/Development/PHP/foo.dev.com/
```

...
    drwx--x--x 8 username username 4096 Apr  3 14:35 public_html

...the apache uid needs READ permission on the directory (and the file). To fix:

```
chmod -R o+r /home/username/Development/PHP/foo.dev.com/
```

Comment: "chmod -R o+r /home/username/" doesn't change anything. The error remains the same. Thank you.

Comment: Then either your apache instance is running under the gid you have reported as 'username' [sic] or the command above was run by a uid without sufficient privelege or there a secondary issue which we can't tell from the information you've provided.

Comment: I've run it with the root user.